# Does Planck’s law imply that there are increasingly more energy levels for fermions to occupy per unit energy interval at higher temperatures?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, thermal-radiation, fermions

Does Planck’s law say -or imply- that (A) there are increasingly more energy levels for fermions to occupy per unit energy interval at higher temperatures so that (B) it takes increasingly more energy to increase the temperature of a star or blackbody with one degree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fermi gases behave just like classical ideal gases if the temperature is high enough to make them non-degenerate, i.e., occupation numbers << 1.  The same is true of Bose gases if the number of particles is constrained.  One cannot say the same for a photon gas, because states with energy < kT will have high occupation numbers.

You can assume that the heat capacity of non-degenerate plasma is ${{C}_{V}}=\tfrac{3}{2}R$ or ${{C}_{P}}=\tfrac{5}{2}R$, per mole of independent particles.

Comment: This is to technical  for me.  If there would be no limit to the mass of a star  made out of a single, unspecified particle species (fermions) -no limit to the number of massive particles it contains,  then I assume  that it's temperature  and density increases as the star is more massive. Am I  right  in assuming that the energy of an increasingly larger part of its particles converges to within a smaller range of (higher) frequencies -so it takes increasingly  more energy to raise the temperature of the star by one degree?

Comment: What I mean  is, do we need increasingly more decimals to express the energy difference between successive (discrete) enegy levels the particles can occupy?

Comment: The energy levels are the same regardless of whether it's a Fermi gas or classical, but the exclusion principle makes a difference.  If the Fermi gas is degenerate at low T, the only likely excitation involves promotion from a filled state just below the Fermi surface to an empty state just above it.  The heat capacity will scale as T^1.  In the high-T case, the heat capacity levels off at the values mentioned.

Comment: Looking at the blackbody curve as plotted from Planck's law (Wikipedia) it looks like the curve becomes ever-higher and narrower at higher and higher temperatures, so wouldn't this fit my assumption as described in my question and comments?

Comment: No, absolutely not.  First of all, Planck's law applies to blackbody radiation, which is a Bose gas.  The shape of the distribution does not change with temperature, if you rescale the axes appropriately.

Comment: Well, while the curve may have the same form at all temperatures when you stretch the wavelength scale (and keep the vertical scale unchanged) for curves at higher  temperatures appropriately: compared to the unchanged (low temperature) wavelength scale the range in which the blackbody radiates most  of its energy seems to shrink at higher temperatures -or am I  wrong?

Comment: You are wrong.  This is an elementary consequence of having the same form.  I don't understand what it is you don't understand.

Comment: Be sure to understand the difference between (1) a Fermi (or classical) gas with a constrained number of particles, and (2) a Bose gas with an unconstrained number of particles.  The behavior is very different.  Your initial question was about Fermi gases, so blackbody radiation is a poor analogy.